# Google Maps v2: about markers

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map in which I have displayed some markers and I would like to identify the marker closest to my current location. How can I focus on that specific marker?

Note: I have found the closest marker based on distance, I just need to know how to display this information on the map.

Comment: Are you looking for `theClosestMarker.showInfoWindow()`?

Comment: That function doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you're asking for, if you've already found out which marker is closest, why don't you simply change the marker's icon?
Some documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_a_marker)

Comment: I've tried to change the marker's icon but for some reason it wouldn't work. I'm simply asking for a way to indicate which marker is the closest without having the user to tap the marker, for example, changing the color of the marker or showing the info window.